# Algebra 2 - Imaginary roots of Polynomials

Tags: polynomials

**Question**:
One zero of $P(z) = z^3 +az^2 + 3z + 9$ is purely imaginary.  If $a \in \mathbb{R}$, find $a$ and hence factorize $P(z)$ into linear factors.

**What I've done**:
I know that the $P(z)$ is real since its coefficients are all real.  The imaginary root must be $bi$ and its conjugate is $-bi$.  For $bi$ and $-bi$, their sum $= 0$ and their product $= -b^2i^2 = b^2$.  These two zeros also come from the polynomial $z^2 + b^2$.
How can I finish the problem with this information?  Thanks $:)$

Edit: Fixed the $az^2$

Comment: Are you sure this is the question? Because $P(bi) = 9 + i(ab + 3b - b^3) \neq 0$...

Comment: @Arthur yes I made a mistake while typing it out, $az$ was supposed to be $az^2$, I fixed it in the question now :)

Comment: Ah ok, that makes it much better. An alternative solution to the one given in the answer below is computing $P(bi)$ and setting it equal to zero.

Comment: @Arthur ok, I'll try that too, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that the term $az$ is meant to be $az^2$ (since the problem doesn't seem to work otherwise):

Equating coefficients in the expansion of $$(z^2+b^2)(z+k)$$

with $z^3+az^2+3z+9$, gives $b=\sqrt{3}$ and $k = a = 3$, and the factorisation is:

$$z^3+az^2+3z+9 = (z-i\sqrt{3})(z+i\sqrt{3})((z+3).$$

Comment: Yes, sorry, the $az$ was supposed to be $az^2$, fixed it.  I will try to solve now by the way you did